# Where to find my system's implementation of standard C library functions?

Tags: c, libc, string.h

for example, the strrev() function. i know that it's declared in string.h, and i wanna to figure out how it is implemented. so where could i the source code?

OS: Windows XP SP3
IDE: Pelles C 6.50 RC3

Comment: As Jonathan says, you should specify what system you're using.

Comment: Also, strrev is not standard C.  See [`string.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/string.h.html) at the Open Group.

Comment: sorry, i thought it was platform-irrelevant.

Comment: and sorry again for the wrong example. but does a file like "string.c" exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to see the source to *an* implementation of the standard C library (albeit one that is in wide use), the source to *glibc* is available. You can clone the *git* repository:

```
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
```

You can also examine the source in a browser. Here's the [string library](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=string;h=db7562c8ad7ffa04e67f18a359a2f8465c28b68a;hb=2543fef229599e8a6e4feeea65ca2dd3f984154f), for instance.

*glibc* does not include `strrev()`. However, if you Google for

```
strrev c
```

you'll get hits to various implementations. For example: http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~kahl/SE2S03/2006/C/strrev.c and ftp://ftp.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/pub/libs/libstrings/strrev.c.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where your particular compiler puts it. Many compilers don't provide the library source code.

Comment: This is an obscure product that I haven't used. How do you know this package includes library source?

Comment: no. it doesn't provide source code files. instead lots of *.lib files are included.